# How can I calculate average packet inter-arrival time on wire-shark with .pcapng file?

Tags: networking, wireshark

How can I calculate average packet inter-arrival time on wire-shark with .pcapng file?

I captured some packets on WIRE-SHARK, and I have to analysis it.
 Of course, I've tried to do some thing about analysis tab on wire shark, but I cannot find effective way to find average packet inter-arrival time .

Are there any efficient way to find it?

Comment: would you like to calculate the frame inter-arrival time for each frame in a flow, or just for each frame seen on the interface?

Comment: I have to calculate former one.

Comment: ok give me a few. I have written a thing called [`pdml2flow`](https://github.com/Enteee/pdml2flow#readme) which does exactly this. I'll quickly draft a plugin for you which should solve this use-case, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a [`pdml2flow`](https://github.com/Enteee/pdml2flow) plugin for this: [pdml2flow-frame-inter-arrival-time](https://github.com/Enteee/pdml2flow-frame-inter-arrival-time).

Currently it is not published to `pip`, therefore you need to `git clone && python setup.py install` the plugin yourself. But once you did that you can:

- Print inter arrival times form your capture `dump.capture`:

```sh
$ tshark -r dump.capture -Tpdml | pdml2flow +frame-inter-arrival-time
{"inter_arrival_times": [7.152557373046875e-07, 0.0, 0.1733696460723877], "frames": null}
{"inter_arrival_times": [3.7670135498046875e-05, 2.3126602172851562e-05], "frames": null}
{"inter_arrival_times": [0.16418147087097168, 0.0007672309875488281, 0.16009950637817383, 0.00016069412231445312, 0.0007240772247314453, 0.15914177894592285, 3.814697265625e-05, 5.245208740234375e-06], "frames": null}
{"inter_arrival_times": [0.1608715057373047, 0.15995335578918457, 2.384185791015625e-07, 2.384185791015625e-07, 2.384185791015625e-07, 0.15888381004333496], "frames": null}
{"inter_arrival_times": [0.16829872131347656, 0.0007762908935546875, 0.14913678169250488, 0.000125885009765625, 0.000736236572265625, 10.19379997253418], "frames": null}
```

- Print inter arrival times with a different flow aggregation. For example by interface, if you captured from multiple interfaces:

```sh
$ tshark -r dump.capture -Tpdml | pdml2flow -f frame.interface_name +frame-inter-arrival-time 
{"inter_arrival_times": [7.152557373046875e-07, 0.0, 0.00018739700317382812, 3.7670135498046875e-05, 2.3126602172851562e-05, 0.008971691131591797, 0.16414976119995117, 4.76837158203125e-07, 3.123283386230469e-05, 0.0007672309875488281, 0.16007304191589355, 2.6464462280273438e-05, 0.00016069412231445312, 0.0007240772247314453, 0.1590421199798584, 2.384185791015625e-07, 2.384185791015625e-07, 2.384185791015625e-07, 9.894371032714844e-05, 3.814697265625e-05, 5.245208740234375e-06, 0.0006232261657714844, 0.15811824798583984, 0.010167837142944336, 1.2636184692382812e-05, 0.0007762908935546875, 0.14911913871765137, 1.7642974853515625e-05, 0.000125885009765625, 0.000736236572265625, 0.16014313697814941, 0.035120248794555664, 0.2039034366607666, 1.907348632, ... ] }
```

- Print arrival times without flow aggregation:

```
$ tshark -r dump.capture -Tpdml |  pdml2flow +frame-inter-arrival-time --no_flow
0.0
7.152557373046875e-07
0.0
0.00018739700317382812
3.7670135498046875e-05
2.3126602172851562e-05
0.008971691131591797
0.16414976119995117
4.76837158203125e-07
3.123283386230469e-05
```

The plugin logic is implemented in:

[`plugin/plugin.py` [a305598]](https://github.com/Enteee/pdml2flow-frame-inter-arrival-time/blob/a3055984e6fbaedab0828b131395927b612e4023/plugin/plugin.py): Calculates the frame inter arrival time

```py
# vim: set fenc=utf8 ts=4 sw=4 et :
from pdml2flow.plugin import Plugin2
from argparse import ArgumentParser

from json import dumps

argparser = ArgumentParser('Calculate inter arrival times of frames in a flow or on an interface')

DEFAULT_NO_FLOW = False
argparser.add_argument(
    '--no_flow',
    action = 'store_true',
    dest = 'no_flow',
    default = DEFAULT_NO_FLOW,
    help = 'Calculate inter arrival time to the previous frame on the interface, not in the flow [default: {}]'.format(
        DEFAULT_NO_FLOW
    )
)

PRINT_FRAMES = False
argparser.add_argument(
    '--frames',
    action = 'store_true',
    dest = 'frames',
    default = PRINT_FRAMES,
    help = 'Print the frames alongside the inter arrival time [default: {}]'.format(
        PRINT_FRAMES,
    )
)

def _get_frame_time(x):
    return x['frame']['time_epoch']['raw']

class Plugin(Plugin2):

    @staticmethod
    def help():
        """Return a help string."""
        return argparser.format_help()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        """Called once during startup."""
        self._args = argparser.parse_args(args)
        self._last_frame_time = None

    def flow_end(self, flow):
        """Calculate and print the frame inter-arrival time."""
        if not self._args.no_flow:
            inter_arrival_times = []
            prev_t = None
            for t in _get_frame_time(flow.frames):
                if prev_t:
                    inter_arrival_times.append(
                        t - prev_t
                    )
                prev_t = t
            print(
                dumps({
                    'inter_arrival_times': inter_arrival_times,
                    'frames': flow.frames if self._args.frames else None
                })
            )

    def frame_new(self, frame, flow):
        """Calculate and print the frame inter-arrival time."""
        if self._args.no_flow:
            frame_time_now = _get_frame_time(frame)[0]

            if not self._last_frame_time:
                self._last_frame_time = frame_time_now

            print(
                frame_time_now - self._last_frame_time
            )
            self._last_frame_time = frame_time_now

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Plugin.help())
```

I hope this helps. Feedback / feature or change requests are always welcome. :)